# App Crashing before view is loaded iOS > 6

Tags: objective-c, exception, ios5, crash

My iOS app runs on iOS 5 and iOS 6, but is focused on features from 6. I recently attempted to test my app in the iOS 5.1 Simulator (Base SDK is 5.0), and it seemed to work fine until I tapped on a button that displays a new view controller with a different class. At this point it crashes and I'm left with only this in the Output Log:

```
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: throwing 0x9e85510 (object 0x9e84780, a NSException)
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x6d6a19 sp=0xbfffe020] for exception 0x9e854f0
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x223dd83 sp=0xbffff200] for exception 0x9e854f0
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x6d6a19 sp=0xbfffe020] for exception 0x9e854f0
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x223dd83 sp=0xbffff200] for exception 0x9e854f0
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x9e854f0 at 0x223de16
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: rethrowing current exception
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x223dddf sp=0xbffff200] for exception 0x9e854f0
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: terminating
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x158eeed sp=0xbffff190] for exception 0x9e854f0
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: catch(id)
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x158eeed sp=0xbffff190] for exception 0x9e854f0
objc[3063]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x9e854f0 at 0x158eeff
```

That's it. I've also set breakpoints in the header and implementation of the class being loaded and none of the breakpoints are ever hit, which means that the app is crashing BEFORE loading the view.

I've never seen anything like this, however I did some research and Google turned up a few things that related to NSArrays and NSPredicate (which my class does have), but I ruled those solutions out because the view is never loaded - so how could an NSArray that hasn't yet been allocated / created be crashing my app?

**Any tips, answers, help would be appreciated!**

**EDIT**:
My project uses:

- Storyboards
- Xcode 4.5
- ARC
- Base SDK is iOS 5.0

There are no extra error logs, debug messages, anything. The above is all I get. I have also tried using `@try / @catch` conditions around certain statements that I thought may have been problematic, but again they were either never called or didn't throw an exception.

My `(id)init` method is also never called.

I'm beginning to think that this is one of those weird Xcode 4 compiler problems again...

**EDIT**:
I have also made sure Autolayout is disabled (although I'm not sure if this is the right place to disable it, this is in the Navigator > File Inspector):

[image]

Comment: Does code execution reach the `init` method of your view controller, before `loadView`?

Comment: @RobertKarl if by `init` you mean `(id)init` then no. It doesn't get to anything.

Comment: What if you wrap the button tap code in @try/@catch and see if there's an exception description or call stack symbols available in the @catch?

Comment: @PhillipMills My project uses Storyboards, so there is no "code" associated with the button press. I have searched the storyboards for problems and unconnected outlets, etc. but have found none. I've tried wrapping all different statements that I thought might be a problem in the try / catch too, but that didn't help.

Comment: my shot: You have autolayout activated for uiviews in your xibs/storyboards, that is a iOS6 only feature.

Comment: I use "AutoSizing" to layout my objects, but Autolayout is not enabled. Maybe I'm just not check for it right? It is currently unchecked in the File Inspector.

Comment: did u also check for each xib/storyboard?

Comment: you should set deployment target to the minimum version of iOS that you intend to support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really still don't understand this error, but using a third party crash-reporting SDK called [*Crittercism*](https://www.crittercism.com) I found the bug:

I was trying to initialize a UICollectionView which is only available in iOS 6 or higher. The strange part is that Xcode seemingly *randomly* decided to tell me about this, because in earlier builds I had used the UICollectionView and successfully run the project in 5.1 simulator (of course I used code to substitute it for a TableView). To me it seems odd that the compiler didn't even reach the `init` or `viewDidLoad` methods.

**This problem only appeared after I updated from Xcode 4.5 (Release, not Developer) to 4.5.1**

Comment: Did you set your xib file's "Document Versioning" field to a "deployment" of iOS 5.0?  (Click on the xib in XCode, then click on the leftmost "document" icon in the Utilities pane.)  Each xib has its own target iOS which might be different from the project's, and might induce better warnings by the compiler.